# can i use TRAN&ROLLBACK for a print preview?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a 'preview' for a report that already exists. As it is programmed now, generating the report changes the Database (it generates an invoice for an order, then generates the report). 
Now i need a way to generate the report without changing the database.
Generating a invoice is easier than deleting it, so i was thinking along these lines :

1. start transaction
2. make invoice
3. read data into object (dataset)
4. rollback transaction
5. feed dataset to report

Is this a good approach? I'm asking because it doesn't 'seem' like the right way to use a transaction.

thanks everybody!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an advisable solution.  You'll be creating locks on tables and bashing the log unecessarily.  The whole idea seems extremely unscalable.

Could you recode to separate the `GenerateInvoice` and `GenerateReport` code into separate stored procedures?  Then either call them separately or add another `DoBoth` stored procedure?

Comment: Agreed. Hate to think what would happen if someone actually wanted to generate an invoice whilst this is going on.

Comment: thank you! I will take another approach. Trying to splitting up the code looks like a good way, but i will need to generate the invoice before i can print it. I will need a way to remove every trace of it afterwards i guess!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Dems, it's not advisable to use transaction for this.

The approach I would use for this sort of problem is usually to add a Param to my StoredProc to know if it's a preview or not.

I would do the same operations, however if it's a Stored Proc that inserts or updates new rows, I'd pull the relevant data into a #TemporaryTable and would edit that data instead of directly editing the real tables.

At the end of my procedure, I simply check if we're previewing or not, and if we're not, I'd insert/update the new rows from my #TemporaryTable.

Comment: +1 I've used this method before and it's much more preferable

Comment: thats exactly how i did it! Thanks everyone!